# Running scripts from usr/local?

Tags: bash

Similar to this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5991/automatically-load-shell-scripts-from-usr-bin), I have a number of scripts (mostly Bash) that I run on documents frequently and would like to access regardless of the current working directory.

Ideally, I would be able run something like `$program foobar` without `$program` being present in the directory, so this needs to tell Bash that the programs are in my path.

Should these files go in the `bin` subdirectory?

First part of the path is as follows:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/Chris/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a cat with many skins, and so has many answers with high degrees of subjectivity, but:

In your home directory, create your own `bin` subdirectory, which you can then add to your `PATH` by way of your `.profile`, for example:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH
```

This directs commands to your bin folder in your home directory, and *then* searches through the rest of your $PATH.

Comment: With some operating systems just making `${HOME}/bin` is enough, because the out-of-the-box shell initialization scripts auto-detect such a directory and alter `PATH` accordingly.

Comment: A personal opinion: I prefer `$HOME/local/bin` so that I can have other "standard" directories (like `share` and others) under `$HOME/local`.

Comment: A cat with many skins, indeed.  You say `~/local/mnt`, I say `~/mnt`.  That's the nice thing about this -- whoever is doing it can arrange it in the way that make the most sense _personally_.

Comment: … which leads into https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/312988/ .